# Why isn't my Wordpress next_posts_link not working with exclude category loop?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I'm trying to setup a loop in Wordpress that will show all posts from one category, which is working just fine, however my problem is that my 'next_posts_link' and 'previous_posts_link' doesn't work. They navigate between pages just fine but the results are the same as the first page all the time.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="main" role="main">

<?php
if (is_home()) {
query_posts("cat=-6");} //Exclude work posts (cat 6) from the news page
?>

<div class="inner">

<h1><?php trim(wp_title("")); ?></h1>

<?php include ('sidebartwo.php'); ?>

<section class="main-wrap twocol news">

<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<article class="box-style">

<time><?php the_time('M d') ?><span><?php the_time('Y') ?></span></time>

<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink()?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?>
</a></h2>

<?php the_content(''); ?>

</article>

<?php endwhile; ?>                              

<div class="next-prev-wrap">

<!-- This is what isn't working properly -->
<span class="next"><?php next_posts_link( 'Older posts', $post->max_num_pages ); ?></span>
<span class="prev"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts', $post->max_num_pages ); ?>
<!-- /end -->

</span>

</div>

</section>      

<?php endif; ?>

</div> <!-- /inner -->

</div> <!-- /main -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I don't think I'm using the right syntax, in fact according to the WP codex page, I don't even think my next/prev links are able to work the way I want it to. How should I approach this?

Comment: If you have found the answer to your own question, you must use the "Your answer" section and mark it as accepted instead of editing the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed myself. This post is now resolved. After much (and I mean much) Googling, I found this article which solved my problem: http://www.dynamicwp.net/articles-and-tutorials/pagination-problem-when-excluding-certain-category-from-blog-main-page/

For reference my new code now looks like this:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="main" role="main">

<?php
if (is_home()) {
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts("cat=-6&paged=$paged");
}
?>

<div class="inner">

<h1><?php trim(wp_title("")); ?></h1>

<?php include ('sidebartwo.php'); ?>

<section class="main-wrap twocol news">

<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<article class="box-style">

<time><?php the_time('M d') ?><span><?php the_time('Y') ?></span></time>

<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink()?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>   </h2>

<?php the_content(''); ?>

</article>

<?php endwhile; ?>                              

<div class="next-prev-wrap">

<span class="next"><?php next_posts_link( 'Older posts', $post->max_num_pages ); ?></span>
<span class="prev"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts', $post->max_num_pages ); ?></span>

</div>

</section>      

<?php endif; ?>

</div> <!-- /inner -->

</div> <!-- /main -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: The answer is in the code snippet posted in my answer...?! The link is just where I got the code from.